# Running "sudo -s" as a user with sudo priv, does not source .bashrc

Tags: bash, sudo, source

I want to be able to run `sudo -s` as a user with sudo priv, and have /root/.bashrc be sourced.
I checked the .bashrc file and the .profile file for /root, both look fine.

Every time I try to use `sudo -s` as a user, .bashrc is never sourced. When running `sudo -i`, .bashrc is sourced.

Why is .bashrc not sourced with `sudo -s` but is sourced with `sudo -i`?

I did not change anything in /root/.bashrc or /root/.profile after deployment that I know of.

/root/.profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi  
fi

mesg n 2> /dev/null || true
```

/root/.bashrc

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi  
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;  
*)
    ;;  
esac
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

**UPDATE:**

I figured out the problem. First of all, the .bashrc file was being sourced the whole time, I just thought it was not because there was no color being applied to the terminal session. To add color to work again I needed to adjust a section in the .bashrc file that was causing problems.

Problem section

```
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
```

Change to the following

```
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
```

Comment: What is the `$SHELL` variable set to as the user you are running `sudo -s` from? Is it possible that it is set to something other than `/bin/bash`? If so, then the interactive shell being started as root will be the same as whatever $SHELL was set to.

Comment: How are you checking if `/root/.bashrc` is being sourced? If you add something like `echo "bashrc is being read!"` into `/root/.bashrc` and then run `sudo -s` do you see the line printed? Also, what operating system are you using and what is your default shell? What's is the output of `echo $SHELL` as Natolio asked?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -s` when run without a command (`sudo -s ls` for instance) starts an interactive shell.
`sudo -i` starts a login shell which sources all of the standard login shell rc files—`.profile`, `.bash_login`.

So everything is working as it should. I frequently use `sudo -s` because I don’t want to change my current directory to the root user’s home.

However if you don't want to use `sudo -i` then `sudo -s bash -l` should work. `bash -l` starts a login shell.

Comment: Ok, then why do I not see this behavior with my other hosts? I am basing this off the color of the text that appears for the cursor when running `sudo -s`, All my other hosts seem to source .bashrc just fine when running `sudo -s`.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there any reason you don't want to use `sudo -i`?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I also removed the incorrect claim about login shells sourcing bashrc (that only happens if `~/.profile` is set to source `~/.bashrc` as is the case in the OP's example and in some Linux distributions). Thing is, `sudo -s` _should_ read .bashrc since it is an interactive non-login shell. So something is weird here.